# can I stop tensorflow training and still safely close tfrecords file from summary writer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I set a large epoch number and I want to stop it early. Simply killing the python process seems not to work (I tried on one training process). This is what I get when I try to read the summary file using tools like summary_iterator **during training or after killed:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorboard_reader.py", line 47, in <module>
    train_loss = reader(train_file[0], ['cost', 'likelihood_loss', 'focal_loss'])
  File "tensorboard_reader.py", line 13, in reader
    for e in tf.train.summary_iterator(filename):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/summary_iterator.py", line 353, in summary_iterator
    for r in tf_record.tf_record_iterator(path):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/tf_record.py", line 77, in tf_record_iterator
    reader.GetNext(status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: truncated record at 27159094
```